# Android Things with Rasp3 7 inch touchscreen

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I have Android Things OS image installed for my Rasp3 and successfully booted up and log in to shell using adb, but lcd display is upside down with my 7 inch touchscreen display.

I wonder if there is config like lcd_rotate=2 in /boot/config.txt on Raspbian?

Comment: Could you please tell me, which touch screen do you use? I'm looking for a "no hassle" touch screen for an Android Things tinker project. :)

Comment: Hi, I bought 7inch touchscreen monitor which is at the link below, but i'm not sure the model is exact the same model as i bought last year ;) ttps://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try to manually mount the boot partition from the sdcard and edit `config.txt`

```
mount -t msdos /dev/sdX1 /mnt/disk
echo 'lcd_rotate=2' >> /mnt/disk/config.txt
```

Where `/dev/sdX1` points to  your sdcard reader device.

*Note: This is more a hack than an officially supported solution, you will have to re-do that operation everytime you upgrade the OS image. It'd be nice to file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Things%20feature%20request) to ask for better support for (dynamic?) display configuration*

Comment: I used virtualbox to mount ext4 volume for i'm using mac (el capitan) and it works!

Comment: can be mounted on mac like as follows

$ sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk1s1 /mnt/sd

Comment: what happens if you omit `-t msdos`?

Comment: I dont know why, but it fails.
`$ sudo mount /dev/disk1s1 /mnt/sd`
`mount: You must specify a filesystem type with -t.`

`$ sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk1s1 /mnt/sd`

`$ ls /mnt/sd`
`LICENCE.broadcom    cmdline.txt         fixup_cd.dat        overlays            start_db.elf        uboot.env (omit)`
OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: @KurosawaHiroyuki usually /dev/disk1 is OSX, try `diskutils list` and see all available disks

Comment: @Fabio's comment has a typo, it's `diskutil list`

Comment: For me the partition was automatically mounted with the name "RPIBOOT" with Ubuntu when inserting the card, was then able to edit config.txt using gedit....

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, but failed mounting the boot partition mentioned in other answers on my Mac OS. 
However, I found the solution and pretty handy finally.

My Solution：
You can simply use Windows OS to mount the TF card with Android Things installed, because the Android Things disk image has a partition with FAT16 format named RPIBOOT containing the CONFIG.txt file which you can append 'lcd_rotate=2' in to resolve the upside down issue on the Raspberry Pi official 7 inch touchscreen.

Bonus：
You can adjust the display resolution in the CONFIG.txt as well, and somehow you would better do it. Otherwise, you will find the 800*480 initial resolution makes things much bigger than you expect if you want to develop some UI in you application, because the touchscreen actually is 7 inches with 240 DPI. The best resolution I got by testing is 1200*720. You can append 2 lines in the CONFIG.txt to make the display look nicer:

```
framebuffer_width=1200
framebuffer_height=720
```