# Android Things: Set screen resolution

Tags: android-things

I have a small screen attached to my Raspberry Pi and according to the [documentation](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD_(B)) for the screen:

> Write the image to a TF card and append the following lines to the config.txt file which is located in the root of your TF card:

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
```

> You must make sure that there are no spaces on either side of the equal sign.

But I can't do this on the Android Things drive, as the disk image is not readable

Comment: these are instructions for the Raspbian OS image, not Android Things. Have you contacted the manufacturer to ask them for support?

Comment: I know what the instructions are for, I need to do the equivalent on the Android things side - is there any way to adjust a config file for the screen dimensions.

Comment: the config file doesn't exist because this is part of Raspbian OS. You should contact the manufacturer asking if they support Android Things

Comment: fyi I might be wrong, see this question where he edits a file inside `/boot/` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558508/screen-orientation-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-android-things

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The original answer was found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165198/android-things-with-rasp3-7-inch-touchscreen/41166605#41166605), and my saviour gave his answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558508/screen-orientation-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-android-things)

Create a mounting position:

`mkdir ~/mnt/sd`

Mount the sd card:

`sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk2s1 ~/mnt/sd`

Make changes to the config.txt, in my case:

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
```

To unmount:

```
sudo umount ~/mnt/sd/
```

Comment: More about HDMI modes of Raspberry Pi [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=24679)