# Android Things 0.5.0-devpreview HDMI output isn't available on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, screen-resolution, android-things

I am using a Samsung monitor and it displays this message

```
"Mode Not Supported. Resolution not supported.  Change the resolution of the external device."
```

I had tried to use different monitor but still can not get the right format output signal.

Display via HDMI is good on 0.4.1-devpreview

Comment: Try to change (set) resolution to 800X600 on Android Things like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41649389/6950238) answer, or change settings on Samsung monitor like in [that](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/923399/resolution-not-supported-change-the-resolution-of-the-external-device-/) discussion. Also, take a look at [this](http://www.fixya.com/support/t14789526-mode_not_supported_resolution_not).

Answer (score -1):

Try to check [Balaji BABU T.R.](https://plus.google.com/117670601284712693018)'s solution from comments to [Wayne Piekarski announce](https://plus.google.com/+WaynePiekarski/posts/Q9zgEVGjGvH) on Google's IoT Developers Community:

> Open config.txt in Notepad ++ paste below things
>
> ```
> # uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
> # and your display can output without overscan
> disable_overscan=1
>
> # uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
> # goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
> #overscan_left=16
> #overscan_right=16
> #overscan_top=16
> #overscan_bottom=16
>
> # uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
> # overscan.
> framebuffer_width=1280
> framebuffer_height=720
>
> # uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
> hdmi_force_hotplug=1
>
> # uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
> hdmi_group=1
> hdmi_mode=1
> ```
>
> HDMI works fine for me after the above settings