# Raspberry does not boot with android things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Wrote Android things image on a micro SDCard and inserted that card into Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and turned on power,At starting it shows 'Auto config Please wait' then the screen remains empty

I had tried connecting it with PC and it is not detected by adb

How could we test whether it is booting OS or not?
Why nothing is shown on the screen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45630906/android-things-0-5-0-devpreview-hdmi-output-isnt-available-on-raspberry-pi-3

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'm pretty sure it's not related to the display, because i can't use adb to access the Raspberry remotely.

Comment: @ferbass, Got it fixed, Actually it was the .img build variant issue

Comment: @ABI I got it fixed by changing my SD card to a Class10 SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was the build that I generated in android things, Initially triggered the *latest* Android things build, which kept on failing to boot, so again triggered another *standard* build that works fine and use *Class10 SD card*s to write the Android Things

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by unziping with https://theunarchiver.com/ which was recommended here https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html

Comment: @ABI, yes I understand. I had same problem while unzipping with mac's "The unarchiver" I had same problem. But didn't get the problem while unzipping with https://theunarchiver.com/.