# Issues with speed and screen resolution when updating to Android Things 0.5.1

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-things

I have a Raspberry pi 3 with the 7" dsi touch screen.  I'm loading an empty bundle factory image of Android Things 0.5.1 and I'm having two possibly related issues.

Firstly, the boot animation is incredibly slow.  Something in the neighborhood of 2 frames a second.

Secondly, once it boots up to the dev preview connection screen the font is larger than it should be.  When I load my app onto the device it is clear that there is something wrong with the resolution or pixel density.

I have tried this on versions 0.5.1 and 0.5.0 and get the same results on both.

Here is my config.txt file

```
kernel=u-boot-dtok.bin
framebuffer_depth=16

# Prevent the firmware from loading HAT overlays now that we handle pin muxing.
# ourselves. See:
# https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md#part3.4
dtoverlay=

dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on

# pwm and I2S are mutually-exclusive since they share hardware clocks.
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan-with-clk,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4
dtoverlay=generic-i2s

start_x=1

# Tell U-boot to always use the "serial0" interface for the console, which is
# set to whichever uart (uart0 or uart1) is set to the header pins. This doesn't
# interfere with the uart selected for Bluetooth.
dtoverlay=chosen-serial0

# Enable skip-init on the UART interfaces, so U-Boot doesn't attempt to
# re-initialize them.
dtoverlay=rpi-uart-skip-init

# Add pin devices to the system for use by the runtime pin configuration driver.
dtoverlay=runtimepinconfig
dtoverlay=uart1
dtoverlay=bcm2710-rpi-3-b-spi0-pin-reorder

# Tell the I2S driver to use the cprman clock.
dtoverlay=bcm2710-rpi-3-b-i2s-use-cprman

# Uncomment to disable serial port on headers, use GPIO14 and GPIO15
# as gpios and to allow the core_freq to change at runtime.
enable_uart=1
core_freq=400

# Enable hardware graphics acceleration.
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,cma-256
mask_gpu_interrupt0=0x400
avoid_warnings=2

# Support official RPi display.
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
dtoverlay=rpi-ft5406
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
```

When I downgrade to 0.4.1 this issues goes away and I get a speedy animation and the screen resolution goes back to normal.

Here is the config.txt for 0.4.1

```
kernel=u-boot-dtok.bin
framebuffer_depth=16
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on

# pwm and I2S are mutually-exclusive since they share hardware clocks.  To
# enable I2S comment out the pwm line and uncomment the generic-i2s line.
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan-with-clk,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4
# dtoverlay=generic-i2s

start_x=1

# Tell U-boot to always use the "serial0" interface for the console, which is
# set to whichever uart (uart0 or uart1) is set to the header pins. This doesn't
# interfere with the uart selected for Bluetooth.
dtoverlay=chosen-serial0

# Enable skip-init on the UART interfaces, so U-Boot doesn't attempt to
# re-initialize them.
dtoverlay=rpi-uart-skip-init

# Uncomment to disable serial port on headers, use GPIO14 and GPIO15
# as gpios and to allow the core_freq to change at runtime.
enable_uart=1
core_freq=400
```

I have tried applying the fix found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534530/android-things-set-screen-resolution) but it did not make a difference.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this possibly related to a display bug reported in 0.5.1 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64774888

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with the screen density with 7" Waveshare 1024x600 display. Display's density isn't identified correctly for some reason. It may be the display's manufacturer issue though.

You can see display reported values with ADB command:

```
adb shell dumpsys display | grep DisplayInfo
```

My display reported 240dpi, though the correct value is 160dpi.

Anyway, I've managed to set the correct density through ADB:

```
adb shell wm density <correct_density_value>
```

Good news is that you only need to set it once per image.