# Change HDMI output resolution

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

Working on a kind of RaspPi Android Things mirror with a vertical screen with resolution 1080p, getDefaultDisplay() method show me WIDTH: 416 HEIGHT: 656 info. 
Is there any way to change the output resolution?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE 1:
The above happened using display_rotate=1. Without the rotation modification the app give me WIDTH: 1824 HEIGHT: 984 values.

Comment: @Jordan the question is highly coupled to Android Things that's the reason. The Android Things OS does not follow the RaspPi rules of configuration.

Comment: Fair enough. I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: @dushu could you explain a bit more where/how you did `display_rotate=1`

Comment: @Blundell here you have ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558508/screen-orientation-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-android-things