# How to rotate hdmi display in Android things 0.5.1?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, iot, android-things

I have Android Things 0.5.1 installed in a Raspberry Pi 3 and connected to a HDMI monitor. But I want to use the monitor in portrait mode, although nothing seems to work. Ive tried with lcd_rotation, and display_rotation, even setting the resolution manually. Any ideas?

Comment: Your HDMI settings in `config.txt`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41166605/6950238) answer of [proppy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656408/proppy).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screen orientation on Raspberry Pi 3 with Android things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558508/screen-orientation-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-android-things)

Comment: Hello Carlos, have you figure out how to do it? I'm having a similar issue using HDMI display plugged to my raspberry PI running Android Things.